Are there two conflicting definitions of the basechange matrix?
Let $B, B'$ be bases for a vector space, and let $v_{[B]}$ be the coordinates of $v$ as a column vector in basis $B$.  Is the basechange matrix $P$ from $B$ to $B'$ defined as $$v_{[B']} = Pv_{[B]}\tag{1}$$ or $$v_{[B']} = P^{-1}v_{[B]}\tag{2}$$
?
It seems to me both definitions are in use. For example, over here, the accepted answers use definition (1), but the OP seems to have thought it should be definition (2).
More authoritatively, Artin writes

Artin seems to be using definition (2)!
It would seem to me that using Artin's definition, the OP's answer is indeed correct!
Interestingly, Artin has a footnote on the page before

If so:

Which of these definitions is preferred or standard?
Why did they change?
Most importantly: How do we keep them clear?

But, at the very least:

Can you confirm that there are indeed two conflicting (opposite) definitions of the basechange matrix in use?


Different authors will use different conventions. As far as I know, the “standard” convention (in particular, the one I use in my books)  is to let the matrix $P$ give the coordinates of the new ^basis* vectors in terms of the old. This agrees with Artin and results in convention (2).

Please don't use images for math content

It is much, much clearer to write change-of-basis matrices as matrix representations of the identity map, i.e., to write them as ${}{B'}[\operatorname{id}]B$ or ${}{B}[\operatorname{id}]{B'}$. The conventions do not matter if one adopts such unambiguous notations. I always wonder why no authors did/do so.

Also the term transition matrix occurs alot, but in my opinion ambiguously.

@MartinBrandenburg I generally don't use images, but think it important here to show the notation and source is exactly verbatim.

@user1551 I don't understand the notation you are advocating.  Would you consider writing it up as an answer?

Let me depart from Artin’s notation. Let $B$ be any ordered basis of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$. I shall denote the coordinate vector of any $v\in V$ with respect to $B$ by ${}_B[v]$. Note that $v$ is a member of $V$ but ${}_B[v]$ is a member of $F^{n\times1}$.
If $B'$ is another ordered basis of $V$, there exists a unique invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$
{}_{B'}[v]=P\,{}_{B}[v]\tag{1}
$$
for all $v\in V$. Equivalently,
$$
{}_{B}[v]=P^{-1}{}_{B'}[v]\tag{2}
$$
for all $v\in V$.
It is important to note that what $(1)$ and $(2)$ describe are changes of coordinates of the same vector under two bases. They are consequences of a change of basis, but the two formulae per se are not descriptions of how basis changes.
In contrast, let $B=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $B'=\{v_1',v_2',\ldots,v_n'\}$. Then every $v_j'$ in the basis $B'$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination:
$$
v_j'=\sum_ic_{ij}v_i.\tag{3}
$$
Now $(3)$ is a genuine change of basis. It directly express each vector in a new basis $B'$ in terms of the vectors in an old basis $B$. We may collect these coefficients to form an $n\times n$ matrix $C=(c_{ij})$. How is $C$ related to $P$? Answer:
$$
C=P^{-1}.
$$
As such,

$P^{-1}$ is the change-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$ (because it is equal to $C$) as well as the change-of-coordinates matrix from $B'$ to $B$ (because of $(2)$);
$P$ is the change-of-basis matrix from $B'$ to $B$ as well as the change-of-coordinates matrix from $B$ to $B'$.

This is where confusion arises: a change-of-basis matrix is also a change-of-coordinates matrix, but the two changes go in different directions. The confusion is serious because most of the time, when one talks about a “change-of-basis matrix” from $B$ to $B'$, one actually intends to mean a change-of-coordinates matrix from $B$ to $B'$, although technically, the two matrices should be inverses to each other.
Anyway, in physics, it is customary to call the transformation of coordinates of vectors “contravariant” to the transformation of basis. In contrast, every linear functional $l$ on $V$ can be represented by a row vector $[l]_B\in F^{1\times n}$ that specifies its coordinates in the dual basis of $B$. If we change the basis of $V$ from $B$ to $B'$, the coordinates of $l$ are changed according to the formula
$$
[l]_{B'}=[l]_{B}\,C.
$$
That is, when the basis of $V$ is changed from $B$ to $B'$, the transformation of coordinates of $l$ is performed by using the change-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$ directly. Physicists say that coordinates of dual vectors (a.k.a. covectors) are transformed “covariantly” to the transformation of the basis of $V$.
We can completely do away with the ambiguities if we express the change-of-basis matrices as matrix representations of the identity map. Recall that given any linear map $T:V\to W$, if $B$ is a basis of $V$ and $B'$ is a basis of $W$, we may express $T$ as a matrix ${}_{B'}[T]_B$ such that
$$
{}_{B'}[Tv]={}_{B'}[T]_B\,{}_{B}[v].
$$
In particular, if $V=W$ and $T$ is the identity map, we have
$$
{}_{B'}[v]={}_{B'}[\operatorname{id}]_B\,{}_{B}[v].\tag{4}
$$
Likewise, we have
\begin{align*}
{}_{B}[v]&={}_{B}[\operatorname{id}]_{B'}\,{}_{B'}[v],\\
[l]_{B'}&=[l]_{B}\,{}_{B}[\operatorname{id}]_{B'},\\
[l]_{B}&=[l]_{B'}\,{}_{B'}[\operatorname{id}]_B.
\end{align*}
Compare $(4)$ with $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that $P$ is just ${}_{B'}[\operatorname{id}]_B$ and $P^{-1}$ is just ${}_{B}[\operatorname{id}]_{B'}$. (Note: although they are matrix representations of the identity map, they are not identity matrix if $B\ne B'$!)
I always find it much, much clearer to write change-of-basis matrices as matrix representations of identity map. I wonder why no authors did/do so.

This is fantastic.  I'm surprised no one else has upvoted it.  Can you expand on when you right multiply by the matrix versus left? This is a tricky point that's easily missed.

@SRobertJames There is nothing special about it. It is just the usual matrix multiplication rule. To multiply an $n\times1$ column vector (such as ${}_B[v]$) by an $n\times n$ matrix, the matrix is placed on the left; to multiply a $1\times n$ row vector (such as $[l]_B$) by an $n\times n$ matrix, the matrix is placed on the right.

Both of these (both $P$ and $P^{-1}$) are clearly change-of-basis matrices, by anyone's definition! One turns a vector in basis $B$ into a vector in basis $B'$, and one turns a vector in basis $B'$ into a vector in basis $B$. The conflict seems to be, not in the definition of the change of basis matrix, but in confusion about which change of basis matrix we mean.
I have seen in use the notation $P_{B \gets B'}$ and $P_{B' \gets B}$ for two matrices (inverses of each other) such that
$$
    v_{[B']} = P_{B' \gets B} v_{[B]}\qquad v_{[B]} = P_{B \gets B'} v_{[B']}.
$$
The notation is unambiguous once you are used to it. The chain rule $P_{A \gets B} P_{B \gets C} = P_{A \gets C}$ holds, which helps us write down formulas for the change of basis matrices, by factoring $P_{B\gets B'}$ as $P_{B \gets E} P_{E\gets B'}$ or $(P_{E \gets B})^{-1} P_{E \gets B'}$.

I'd argue the notation is still just as ambiguous, since there's no indicator if $P_{B \gets B'}$ changes basis vectors $B'$ to basis vectors $B$, or changes a vector in coordinates of $B'$ to coordinates in $B$.

I think this confusion comes from the fact that vector spaces are naturally isomorpic to their duals' duals, and therefore the one basis change matrix of a space corresponds to the other basis change matrix of its dual space and there is no natural choice between the two.

@SRobertJames Exactly, you nailed it.

You're probably right.  Mainly it's the direction.   Other than that it seems pretty clear.
The one thing I find easy to remember is that the matrix with given columns will take vectors in that basis to their expression in whatever basis those columns are expressed in. This is simply because of the fact that applying a matrix to the standard basis vectors gives you back the columns.
Of course the literature can be confusing on this.
Also confusing is when they talk about contra and covariance.
All the more reason to use this rule of thumb.

There are indeed two opposite definitions here.  Now, conflicting definitions are common in math (is $0$ a natural number? is a constant sequence increasing?), but what's unique here - the only example I'm aware of - is that the two definitions are completely opposite.  Aside from the trivial case of changing a basis to itself, they never agree.
The root of this problem seems not to be a lack of convention, but an inherent property.  As explained clearly by this 3blue1brown article, if $P$ changes basis vectors $B$ to basis vectors $B'$, then $P$ also changes vectors in coordinates $B'$ to coordinates $B$:

Conversely, if $Q$ changes vectors in coordinates $B$ to coordinates $B'$, then $Q$ changes the basis vectors themselves of $B'$ to the basis vectors of $B$.
Changing basis vectors is a coordinate-free operation.  There's no need to specify a coordinate system or distinguished basis we're working in.  In our abstract vector space, $B$ is one set of vectors, $B'$ is another, and either can be used as a basis.  $P$ changes $B$ to $B'$. And $P$ can be defined simply as the unique linear transformation which maps each vector of $B$ to its corresponding vector of $B'$.  It is perhaps for this reason that many prefer definition (2).
On the other hand, I'd argue that changing coordinates is the more practical and useful operation, which suggests definition (1).  It's harder to define $Q$ this way, but, once we do, $Q$ is closer to the way we will use it.  We need to change coordinates much more frequently than we need to actually change the basis itself.
Given that the issue is already confusing, perhaps the best is to avoid using the term entirely, and simply speak out what you mean (e.g. "Let $Q$ be the matrix which changes a vector in coordinates $B$ to coordinates $B'$".)

Artin names "coordinate vectors" the components of the vector in a given basis. What do you mean here by "coordinates", in particular when you say "...We need to change coordinates much more frequently than we need to actually change the basis itself...."?

@Kan't I mean "We very frequently are given one form of coordinates (that is, the components of a vector $v$ in basis $b$) and need to change them to a different form (that is, the components of the same vector $v$ but in a different basis $b'$).  We need to do this much more frequently than we need to transform the vectors comprising $b$ to the vectors comprising $b'$."

In the vector space $V$, if (the only coherent option, IMO) the basechange matrix $P$ from $B=(e_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ to $B'=(e'_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ is defined by the positions (summation convention):
$$e'_i=P_i^je_j,\space\space i=1,\dots,n\tag1$$
then, given any ("column") vector $v\in V$, we get:
$$v'^ie'_i=v^je_j$$
namely (by $(1)$):
$$v'^iP_i^je_j=v^je_j$$
and hence (by the linear independence of the basis vectors):
$$v^j=P_i^jv'^i,\space\space j=1,\dots,n$$
whence finally:
$$v'^j=(P^{-1})_i^jv^i,\space\space j=1,\dots,n\tag2$$
The confusion arises because you call $P$ the "basechange matrix from $B$ to $B′$", but then you misuse it in $(1)$ as the transformation matrix of "coordinate vectors" (Artin's terminology) under the basechange from $B$ to $B′$". It is like one said that, <<since 1 km = 1000 m>> (basechange), then <<distance (km) = 1000 $\times$ distance (m)>> (coordinate vector transformation) !
So, to choose one, I'd definitely go with your $(2)$/Artin's 2nd Ed., provided that $P$ is what it is: the basechange matrix from $B$ to $B'$. The key point is that basis vectors and ("column") vectors' components (rightly said "contravariant") change inversely from each other. (Btw, that's precisely the nice feature of the physical quantities: the bigger their unit of measure, the smaller the number they are represented with, in those UOM.)

Can you explain more clearly why you feel that definition is "(the only coherent option"?

Added some text to answer your comment.
